# Netlify build failed for npm error in react app

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-scripts

this is the failed build log from netlify build log. I build this yesterday. Now I am having problem with building the site

```
10:16:47 AM: Starting build script
10:16:47 AM: Installing dependencies
10:16:47 AM: Python version set to 2.7
10:16:47 AM: Downloading and installing node v16.15.1...
10:16:47 AM: Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v16.15.1/node-v16.15.1-linux-x64.tar.xz...
10:16:48 AM: Computing checksum with sha256sum
10:16:48 AM: Checksums matched!
10:16:51 AM: Now using node v16.15.1 (npm v8.11.0)
10:16:51 AM: Started restoring cached build plugins
10:16:51 AM: Finished restoring cached build plugins
10:16:51 AM: Attempting ruby version 2.7.2, read from environment
10:16:52 AM: Using ruby version 2.7.2
10:16:52 AM: Using PHP version 8.0
10:16:53 AM: No npm workspaces detected
10:16:53 AM: Started restoring cached node modules
10:16:53 AM: Finished restoring cached node modules
10:16:53 AM: Installing NPM modules using NPM version 8.11.0
10:16:54 AM: npm WARN config tmp This setting is no longer used.  npm stores temporary files in a special
10:16:54 AM: npm WARN config location in the cache, and they are managed by
10:16:54 AM: npm WARN config     [`cacache`](http://npm.im/cacache).
10:16:54 AM: npm WARN config tmp This setting is no longer used.  npm stores temporary files in a special
10:16:54 AM: npm WARN config location in the cache, and they are managed by
10:16:54 AM: npm WARN config     [`cacache`](http://npm.im/cacache).
10:16:56 AM: npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
10:16:56 AM: npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
10:16:56 AM: npm ERR!
10:16:56 AM: npm ERR! While resolving: react-reveal@1.2.2
10:16:56 AM: Creating deploy upload records
10:16:56 AM: npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
10:16:56 AM: npm ERR! node_modules/react
10:16:56 AM: npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.2" from the root project
10:16:56 AM: npm ERR!   peer react@">= 16.8.0" from @formspree/react@2.2.4
10:16:56 AM: npm ERR!   node_modules/@formspree/react
10:16:57 AM: Failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1 (https://ntl.fyi/exit-code-1)
10:16:56 AM: npm ERR!     @formspree/react@"^2.2.4" from the root project
10:16:56 AM: npm ERR!   8 more (@testing-library/react, react-dom, react-icons, ...)
10:16:56 AM: npm ERR!
10:16:56 AM: npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
10:16:56 AM: npm ERR! peer react@"^15.3.0 || ^16.0.0" from react-reveal@1.2.2
10:16:56 AM: npm ERR! node_modules/react-reveal
10:16:56 AM: npm ERR!   react-reveal@"^1.2.2" from the root project
10:16:56 AM: npm ERR!
10:16:56 AM: npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@16.14.0
10:16:56 AM: npm ERR! node_modules/react
10:16:56 AM: npm ERR!   peer react@"^15.3.0 || ^16.0.0" from react-reveal@1.2.2
10:16:56 AM: npm ERR!   node_modules/react-reveal
10:16:56 AM: npm ERR!     react-reveal@"^1.2.2" from the root project
10:16:56 AM: npm ERR!
10:16:56 AM: npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
10:16:56 AM: npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
10:16:56 AM: npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
10:16:56 AM: npm ERR!
10:16:56 AM: npm ERR! See /opt/buildhome/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
10:16:56 AM: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
10:16:56 AM: npm ERR!     /opt/buildhome/.npm/_logs/2022-06-14T04_16_54_367Z-debug-0.log
10:16:56 AM: Error during NPM install
10:16:56 AM: Build was terminated: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1
10:16:57 AM: Failing build: Failed to build site
10:16:57 AM: Finished processing build request in 13.567112014s
```

I am guessing this is probably for NPM. Should I delete my installed dependency and again reinstall them using --force flag?
I am using npm version 8. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was facing same issue while deploying to Netlify and all the checks on my PRs were failing. After a little searching around, found the solution mentioned in Netlify forums here - [Fix for Build was terminated: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1](https://answers.netlify.com/t/deploy-failed-today-build-was-terminated-build-script-returned-non-zero-exit-code-1/64450/2)

In my case, I was able to get the issue resolved by adding the **--force** flag after the build command `npm run build --force`.
Also, had to set the `NODE_VERSION` env variable to `16.15.0` in Netlify as apparently the issue has occurred in Node version `16.15.1` and that was the version which was being used for build.

That's the same Node version mentioned in your post -

> 10:16:51 AM: Now using node v16.15.1 (npm v8.11.0)

There are few other solutions mentioned as well on the link provided above if the one's I used don't work for you.

Comment: Thank you so much, you solved the problem. i added the --legacy-peer-deps in the environment variable in netlify under the build and deploy section. I got the solution from the link you mentioned.